# Redefined ctrl key: can I obtain multiple strokes by holding?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, delete, xmodmap

I have redefined my right ctrl key to delete, using

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Delete"
```

and this works very nicely, except that whenever I hold the key, it deletes only once. Of course, I can highlight a sentence and delete it all with one press, but it would be very nice to be able to hold the key down, and have it continuously delete (as the the normal del key does).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xset` to enable the auto-repeat feature.

Run `xset` without parameters to see the usage:

```
To turn auto-repeat off or on:
-r [keycode]        r off
 r [keycode]        r on
 r rate [delay [rate]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This does change the behavior, but not in the intended way. Most notably, the repeat rate is **very** high, and is not affected by `xset r 105 r rate 250 2` -- when held, Left Ctrl deletes a fullscreen line of text in gedit in an instance. Secondly, held in terminal, it does not continue to delete, it deletes once and then prints `5~` multiple times.